# How to make requests to server from Android applications

Tags: android, android-asynctask, software-design

I'm currently developing an application on Android platform that needs to contact the main server multiple times to do various stuff. I'm now coping with the issue of software design in terms of making every request to the server in a separate thread (otherwise, I get a *NetworkOnMainThreadException* and it's not recommended to do so).

So I have 3 classes in my example:

- **The requester** class that wants to, say, fill up a Spinner with data from a database located in a server.
- **The middle class** that asks a DBConnection to perform a new connection, then wait for it to finish and parse the data to the appropriate format.
- **The lower class** that makes the connection to the database and retrieves a raw String, which then is passed to the middle class to be parsed.

I know that for every connection made to the server, I'll have to create a new thread, so that's made in the class that establishes the connection (lower class) and waits for results. This way I don't overload the top layers of my software with AsyncTasks and stuff that they shouldn't be aware of.

The problem is that after I receive the data I have to parse it, and the do stuff with it. Also I have to fill up the spinner (as in the example).

I know it might be a good idea to make a DataFromServerListener interface or something like that, but I think it's gonna get cluttered with methods all around to handle data from server. On the other hand, I'd have to make every top class start the separate thread with an AsyncTask and might not be the best solution.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions on this subject. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of what I needed. Actually, it solves problems I didn't take care of before.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162201/Painless-AsyncTask-and-ProgressDialog-Usage

Answer (score 0):

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return "Executed";
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
    }
}
```